# Selenium and Junit: Does it make sense?

Tags: selenium, junit

Simply, given that Selenium is a testing tool, it seems redundant to combine Junit with Selenium tests. Does one write the Selenium test and then a separate Junit test of the Selenuium test or should there be only the Junit-annotated test -- that is, normally when one writes code and tests, you write a Java class and the a separate Junit test which exercises that class.

So firstly: does it make sense to use Junit and Selenium and secondly: if you do, would you have the Selenium test and a Junit test or just a single test which is a Junit-annotated test with Selenium statements in it? Would a normal project have one or two files for each "tested thing."

Comment: Selenium is a browser driver, it lets arbitrary code interact with a browser. Junit is a test framework, it lets you write and run tests. Together, they let you write and run tests that interact with a browser. But often you move the interaction detail into *page objects*, so it's not as simple as one file or two.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a testing tool that is aimed at testing a browser-based user-interface, while JUnit is a testing tool that is designed for unit-tests and tests classes/components through their programmatic interfaces.

As Selenium and JUnit are focussed at completely different aspects of testing, they should be seen as complementary tools that can easily be used in the same project. As they have different testing scopes, the tests written for each tool should live in different files.